# Media not found Exception In Email Business Process (Hybris)

Tags: email, media, sap-commerce-cloud, business-process-management

I've created a process to be able send email to the user on order confirmation. 
The problem is that on the DEV environment everything goes well but when I did a deploy to UAT server 
I got an exception during the task execution ( " Media not found (requested media location: hf0/h27/8861015965726.bin) ").
Any Ideas what could be happening ?
How can this issue be resolved and what causes this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hybris creates emails using Velocity templates. Those Velocity Templates are stored as Medias on the hybris Servers. hybris Medias consist of two parts: an entry in the respective table in the database and a file on the hard drive. The database entry stores metadata about that media while the file stores the actual content.

Now what hybris is telling you, is that the file on the hard drive is missing. The database entry directs to a file that is not existing. There could be a lot of reasons why that file is missing:

- It was deleted during deployment.
- It wasn't created during deployment.
- The hybris server has no access/access rights to that directory.
- In a clustered environment the file could have been stored on another node and is not accessible on the current node.

Answer (score 0):

Media could be the email itself as Johannes stated, but it can also be a part of the email, an image set from the CMS cockpit for example.

To fix this issue you have to master your impex flows.

First be sure that impex contain all the data needed to create properly the email.

Then know what is imported when you deploy and update your system.

Be sure that mandatory files are imported during initialization.

Be sure that data that can be managed by webmasters are not reset by impex during update.

If a data is created during the update because init is already done then be sure that is won't be played after each update.

Answer (score 0):

As the media file is not found, you can 
1. go to hmc-->Multimedia-->Media, in search panel, 
2. click "search additional attributes" dropdown box, select "PK of file"
3. use "8861015965726" as PK of file to search

Then you can find out what file is missing and you can import impex or upload using hmc to fix this problem.